# Typing in one input field disabling other input field using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Suppose we have two input fields if we start typing in one input field other one would be disabled and vice-versa. How can we write a logic using react js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: We have two input tag eg: <input type="text" placeholder="A"  /> <input type="text" placehplder="B"  />.  either one of them can be writable. If we start typing in A input tag B should be disabled. Or if we start typing in B input tag A should be disable.

Comment: Edit your main question with the code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will have to define what it means to be typing. Generally, it could be done by setting a `timeOut` of some milliseconds after each keystroke (and if necessary, restarting it).

Roughly you can achieve the "typing state check" with this (note that the example is very simplified!):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isTyping: false,
    inputValues: {
      input1: '',
      input2: '',
      input3: ''
    }
  }
}

const handleChange = (event, label) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({inputValues: {...inputValues, [label]: event.target.value}, isTyping: true}), setTimeout(revertIsTypingToFalse, 500))
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'input1')} value={this.state.inputValues.input1} disabled={this.state.isTyping}>
      <input onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'input2')} value={this.state.inputValues.input2} disabled={this.state.isTyping}>
      <input onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'input3')} value={this.state.inputValues.input3} disabled={this.state.isTyping}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

(revertIsTypingToFalse would be a function that does what it says - sets `isTyping` state back to false)

Now, to disable all of them when you start typing you could add this to `<input>`:

```
<input ...
  disabled={isTyping}
/>
```

But naturally you want to keep the input box that you are currently typing to enabled. To do that, you could save the label of last input that you were typing into state like this:

```
handleChange(event, label){
  this.setState(prevState => ({inputValues: {...inputValues, [label]: event.target.value}, isTyping: true, lastInput: label}), setTimeout(revertIsTypingToFalse, 500))
}
```

(remember to add `lastInput` into state at constructor!)

Now you can disable all the inputs that are not being typed into by comparing the last used input label to individual input boxes labels, like this:

```
<input
  ...
  disabled={isTyping && lastInput !== 'input1'}
/>
```

Voula, there you have it!

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below code it worked fine:

```
class Typing extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { input1: false, input2: false }
 }
 handleinput1() {
this.setState( {input1: false, input2: true} )
} 
 handleinput2() {
 this.setState( {input1: true, input2: false} )
} 
 render() {
   return(
     <div>
     <input type="text"
            placeholder= " input 1 "
            disabled = {(this.state.input1)}
            onInput = {this.handleinput1.bind(this)}
            />
     <input type="text" 
         placeholder= " input 2 "
         onInput = {this.handleinput2.bind(this)}
         disabled = {(this.state.input2)}/>
    </div>
);
  }
 };

  React.render(<Typing />, document.getElementById('root'));
```